# Flag an answer with the same code as in the question

Tags: support, accepted-answer, declined-flags

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10987840/601179) the OP asks <sub>(not)</sub>  a <sub>(real)</sub> question, and showing what he tried.
His code works just as it is, he got several comments plus a DEMO  showing him his code works.

Someone wrote an answer with the **exact** (working) code as in the question, and it was accepted.
I flagged the answer and it was declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I wasn't speaking about "technical inaccuracies", as I even commented on the answer:

> It was accepted, and it has the same code as in the question... ?!

Wasn't my flag justified? If it was not, I'm not getting what *"technical inaccuracies"* are.

Comment: What would you have the mod do about this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Close and delete, not just the answer. I flagged the question before it got any answer, the flag was "helpul" but the question remained opened...

Comment: Your comment reads as "I don't agree this should have been accepted" at first glance. So, what should a moderator do about that? Just downvote the answer. If you want to close the question, vote to close it or clearly state what it is you want to happen and why. I have been successful in the past clearly explaining that "there is no real problem to begin with".

Comment: @Bart. I tried all that... I voted to close the question, I flagged the question, and I would have wrote a comment on the question, but there were two already. I think my arsenal got dry... :(

Comment: @gdoron The question seems to be closed now. I flagged it, providing an explanation. Although I can't be sure that it was my flag that got picked up or if something else triggered it.

Comment: @Bart. I would love to know what was the flag text if you don't mind...

Comment: I flagged it with "This question is better off closed. As stated in the comments, the code in the question should work just fine. Subsequently the accepted answer (with the exact same code) is accepted as correct. So it seems there was no problem to begin with. I see no reason to leave it opened." But as I said, I'm not sure that was the cause of the closure.

Comment: *Somewhere* on the internet *someone* is wrong.  You don't have to put so much effort into this particular case, save some for the rest.

Comment: @gdoron: [Victory!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987840/check-existance-of-an-element-inside-other-element-with-jquery)

Comment: @thirtydot. `:)`, about time... that was one of the stupidest question on SO. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Your flag isn't a great one.  It says:

> This whole "question" is stupid. the OP code should work. he accepted an answr that just pasted his exact code. What the ???

There doesn't appear to be anything actionable there.  If you want a greater chance of the moderator acting on the flag, tell him what you want him to do.

Comment: I would delete the question... But it's up to the mod to decide, I'm just "flagging". Isn't it?

Comment: What policy is the OP violating, exactly?

Comment: Asking not a real question of course...

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere.  But that doesn't really have anything to do with the answer, does it?  I've checked the OP and the answer for cross-voting, none found, so I think we're done.

Comment: Of course it does. If I'm asking you : _"How do I  increment `x` in C#? I tried `x++` but it doesn't work"_ And you answer: _"`x++`"_ Don't you think there is something wrong with the answer? not just _"technical inaccuracies"_

Comment: Then vote to close the question. Perhaps as "not a real question". If the question is the problem to begin with, go to the source.

Comment: @Bart. I tried all that... I voted to close the question, I flagged the question, and I would have wrote a comment on the question, but there were two already. I think my arsenal got dry... :(

Comment: That's bad luck then. Usually I'm quite successful in cases like these if I clearly explain the problem and my intent. The less work a mod has to do to understand the issue, the better your chances.

Comment: Then just let it be? @gdo

Comment: @slhck. I might do that from now on, but I don't think keeping not real questions is wise, but I'm too old for fighting... (BTW, the question flag was "helpful")